# Squaring complex number equation with absolute values

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, absolute-value, sums-of-squares

I don't understand how you go from the first to the second line in this problem :

$$|(a-k)+i(7-2a)|=|(a-2)+i(9-2a)|$$

$$(a-k)^2+(7-2a)^2=(a-2)^2+(9-2a)^2.$$

Firstly, squaring i should make it -1 I believe, it just seemed to disappear here?
Second, shouldn't the square be applied to the whole of the left and right parts of the equation and not just the individual parts between brackets?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you the definition of $|z|$ for a complex number $z$?

Comment: To make more explicit what @KaviRamaMurthy is pointing to, in going from the first line to the second line, they are *not* squaring both sides, they are evaluating the norm (of complex numbers.) The complex norm is written the same way as the absolute value for real numbers, so that might be a source of some confusion for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Kavi Rama Murthy said and noting that in both the RHS and LHS, the expressions in the absolute value function are just two complex numbers; $a$ and $k$ are just constants, recall the definition of the absolute value in the argand diagram.

- $z$ is the net vector addition of $x$ and $y$, hence $z = x+iy$
- The distance or magnitude of the vector $z$ is the same as the $|z|$

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I get it now! It stems from |z| = sqrt{a^2 + b^2} like you mentioned, so i is gone and we can throw out the square root on both sides too.

Comment: To go from a+ bi to $a^2+ b^3$ you **don't** square it!  You multiply by a- bi.

Comment: I think you may be confusing what $i$ actually represents. The $i$ is not gone, but it was never present in the definition of the absolute value above. The term $i$ is the imaginary unit, a Vector, that tells us the direction - the imaginary axis(up if positive and down if negative). The term multiplied by it is the magnitude, hence we move $y$ units in the imaginary axis or we add the vector $iy$.